# androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

Tags: javascript, android, xml, androidx

I have an Android app. This app has ten activities, the first activity of which is the Splash Screen that is run thats After one or two seconds, the app closes and does not enter the second activity The error I get is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 4538
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.IntroPage}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
        at com.example.myapplication.IntroPage.onCreate(IntroPage.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

thats my xml splash screen code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen"
    android:background="@color/White">



    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_gif"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="289dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.296" />


    <androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.005"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
        android:id="@+id/spin_kit"
        style="@style/SpinKitView.WanderingCubes"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:SpinKit_Color="@color/orange"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_gif"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.254" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/powerd_by_maede"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spin_kit"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.48"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

thats my xml for sec activity:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#9bfa5e">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="435dp"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/layoutDots"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/layoutDots"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/layoutDots" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:background="#222"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chevron_right"
        android:textColor="#222"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btn_skip"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="رد کردن"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layoutDots"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

thats my splash screen activity:

```
   package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.sprite.Sprite;
import com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.style.DoubleBounce;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedP;
    boolean show_intropage=true;
    Calendar taqwim = Calendar.getInstance();
    int today,date_mod;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);


        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //----progress---------------
        ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        Sprite doubleBounce = new DoubleBounce();
        progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(doubleBounce);

        today = taqwim.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

        sharedP = getSharedPreferences(Items.SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        show_intropage = sharedP.getBoolean(Items.INTROPAGE,true);

        sharedP.edit().putInt(Items.TODAY, today).apply();




        if (show_intropage){

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

          Intent Myintent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,IntroPage.class);
                startActivity(Myintent);
                finish();

            }
        },4000);

           date_mod = taqwim.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
           // Toast.makeText(this, day+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sharedP.edit().putInt(Items.DATE_MODIFIED, date_mod).apply();


    }else {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Intent Myintent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(Myintent);
                    finish();

                }
            },4000);
        }
    }
}
```

thats my sec activity:

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.RotateUpTransformer;


public class IntroPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager MyviewPager;
    Button btnSkip, btnNext;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;

    SharedPreferences sharedP;

    int [] layout = {R.layout.slide_01,R.layout.slide_02,R.layout.slide_04};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro_page);


        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        MyviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
        MyviewPager.setAdapter(new ViewP());

        MyviewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new RotateUpTransformer());
        sharedP = getSharedPreferences(Items.SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        addBottomDots(0);


        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int Tedad_items = MyviewPager.getCurrentItem()+1;

                if (Tedad_items < layout.length) {

                    MyviewPager.setCurrentItem(MyviewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);

                } else {

                    startActivity(new Intent(IntroPage.this,MainActivity.class));
                    finish();

                }

            }
        });

        btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(IntroPage.this,MainActivity.class));
                finish();

            }
        });

        MyviewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                addBottomDots(position);

                if (position == layout.length - 1) {
                    // btnNext.setText("Start");
                    btnNext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);
                    btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    //  btnNext.setText("Next");
                    btnNext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chevron_right);
                    btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });

    }

    public  class ViewP extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            View view= LayoutInflater.from(IntroPage.this).inflate(layout[position],container,false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layout.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

            // View view = (View)object;
            container.removeView((View) object);


        }
    }
    private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        dots = new TextView[layout.length];

        int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
        int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[0]);
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
        }

        if (dots.length > 0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is here:

> `dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);`

In your layout you are using a `LinearLayoutCompat`.
Use:

```
LinearLayoutCompat dotsLayout;
dotsLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness